# Error log not created

Tags: magento2.2, log, error-log, magento-2.2.1

After **Magento 2.2.1** CE upgrade I ended up situation that **error report** file is not created to `/var/report` directory.

> There has been an error processing your request
>   Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: **xxxxxxx**"

**Is there a developer mode which can show the error directly in browser?** All advises are welcome.

Comment: what are the permissions on the folders?

Comment: Full, It It has been working in old versions....

Comment: hmm so 777? that's a risk xD ok, if it's 777 then that shouldn;'t be the cause, how about the owners?

Comment: it has been 775 and 777 for the test. It didn't help

Comment: I mean the owner, not permissions :) should be something like user : webdev

Comment: yes, that is fine.

Comment: ok then will add an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, yes there is. To enable the developer mode you need access to your terminal, in the magento root run this command:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

this sets Magento to developer mode, which displays errors in the browser for the "developer" to see. You can also achieve this (if the screen is just white) with the below code added into `index.php`:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
register_shutdown_function('fatal_handler');
function fatal_handler()
{
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo ('<pre>');

    var_dump($error);
}
```

this should be enough to get the error on screen. If not, check your server error logs as opposed to Magento's to see if it's added there.

Comment: So far , No success.

Comment: @user61125 what does going to a page look like after setting mode to developer?

Answer (score 0):

You can print directly to browser by renaming one of the files.

Rename `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml` in *magento_root/pub/errors* directory.

Answer (score 0):

The design theme contained the following declaration:

```
<block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="earos.pdp.after" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/footer.phtml"/>
```

You need to change it to:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="earos.pdp.after" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/footer.phtml"/>
```